# Populating SELECT with large JSON data set via ColdFusion (Lucee) very slow

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, lucee, large-data

Please forgive me if I have provided more information than required for this question. :D

I am building an application that pulls large JSON data-sets from a remote machine.  However, I am working within a secure environment that separates application servers with firewalls, etc.  Because of this I have had to do a bit of fudging (using SSH) to get the data I need.  I have requested additional ports to be opened so I could bypass using SSH but was denied.

Here is the physical path to get my data over SSH:  **My Application Server** -> **Secure Server with Curl** -> **Multiple unique application servers with JSON data**.

To abide by the security rules; I wrote the CFML code below on my application server.  (server is running Linux, Lucee 4.5, MySQL and Apache)

```
<cfset secure_server = "secure_server.my.example.com">
<cftry>
    <cfexecute 
    name="/usr/bin/ssh" 
    arguments="#secure_server# ./RemoteDirectory/server_list.sh" 
    timeout="10" 
    variable="server_list">
    </cfexecute>
    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfoutput>
            #cfcatch.message#<br>#cfcatch.detail#<br>
        </cfoutput>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

The above code simply SSHs to the secure server and runs a script called server_list.sh.  The important bit of the script is below:

```
curl -s -k -b cookie.jar -c cookie.jar https://unique_application_server/Path/To/Server/list -H "Accept:application/json"
```

That curl script returns a JSON string that looks similar (but with far more data) to this:

```
{
  "os" : "Linux ",
  "fqdn" : "server1.my.example.com",
  "disk_status" : "OK",
  "system_model" : "HP",
  "type" : "Server"
},
{
  "os" : "Linux ",
  "fqdn" : "server2.my.example.com",
  "disk_status" : "OK",
  "system_model" : "Dell",
  "type" : "Server"
},
```

The amount of JSON data sent, at this time, is about 3MB.  However, that data will grow exponentially over time.

Once I get the JSON back to my application server; I use CF's deserializeJSON function then grab just the field I need.  In this case its the FQDN field.  Since the data from the JSON is a full domain, I needed to chomp just the hostname.  The "new_label" code takes care of that.  There is probably a better REGEX or a better method than the one I am using, but this works.

```
<cfset arrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(server_list)>
<select multiple="multiple" class="searchable" name="searchable[]">
    <cfloop array="#arrayOfStructs#" index="PARENT">
        <cfset new_label = ReReplace(PARENT.fqdn, "(.[^.]*)$", "")>
        <cfset new_label = ReReplace(new_label, "(.[^.]*)$", "")>
        <cfset new_label = ReReplace(new_label, "(.[^.]*)$", "")>
        <cfoutput><option value="#PARENT.fqdn#">#new_label#</option></cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</select>
```

The above code populates the field with the hostnames of servers from the JSON.  The OPTION field would look something like this:

```
<option value="server1.my.example.com">server1</option>
```

A couple things of note that may (or may not) help.  I am using jQuery and a multi-select.js that turns the SELECT into a side-by-side field.  The multi-slect is from here: http://loudev.com/

Second, all servers in the path are fairly powerful and are all connected over 10gb.  So besides the firewalls between, there should not be any bottle necks.

No matter the browser I use, the code above works, but is rather slow when it populates the hostname field.  Because the JSON data I am pulling updates about every minute, I am not able to store it long term in the database on my application server.

Knowing all that, my question is:  How could I speed up the form field so the user does not have to wait for the page to load 2500+ servernames?

Could I leverage jQuery or the MySQL database to speed things up without running into stale data?  Could it simply be my method of getting the hostname from the FQDN?  Should I scrap this method and try something else?  Have I overlooked something here on Stack that has my answer?  (I spent a lot of time searching Q/A here but found nothing.  Perhaps I was not looking hard enough.)

Any other information you nice folks need?  Thanks! :D

UPDATE --

@Alex.  I do that very test now.  Code is below.  Good suggestion though!

```
<cfset tickBegin = GetTickCount()>
<!--- THE CODE THAT RUNS THE JSON QUERY ABOVE --->  
<cfset tickEnd = GetTickCount()>
<cfset testTime = tickEnd - tickBegin>
<cfoutput>Page(#testTime#ms)</cfoutput>
```

As far as caching the data, that is part of my question.  How to cache?  What method to use?  How can I cache the JSON without displaying stale data?  Is this an instance where AJAX would be useful?

UPDATE 2 --

Could I be going about this the wrong way?  I know that sometimes you will need to display large amounts of data back to your users.  Would simply adding a BlockUI and a progress bar stating please wait be an OK solution?  I would prefer to figure out a better solution honestly but I am open to suggestions for sure! Thoughts?

Comment: Measure the time taken for each step in your flow. Use `getTickCount()` to do so. Then you can analyse if the time taken is acceptable. Regardless, why not just cache the retrieved server list for a short period of time?

Comment: In addition to the suggestions about caching - *RE: I do that very test now*  So how much time does each part take? ie 1. Retrieving 2. Deserializing 3. Generating <options> list 4. Display in the browser?  *RE: wait for the page to load 2500+ servernames?* The form is not actually displaying 2500 options, is it?

Comment: The JSON that I pull in from the "secure server" is sent in one big chunk due to how Curl works (i assume) which takes about 20ms.  It then hits the serialize in CF which takes about 50ms.  I then time the form field, which does indeed have 2500+ items that will grow.  That takes about 200ms but it "seems" much longer.  I assume it seems longer because it takes such a long time for the browser to parse that into a form field.  All 2500+ fields do display ... A large amount, I know.  Not sure how else to do it.

Comment: Well 2500 items is too much for a select list IMO. Autosuggest is one way of avoiding large select lists, usually in conjunction with some sort of caching (which would probably be a good idea anyway). However, the data needs to be in a search friendly format for fast access.

Comment: Thank you, Leigh.  I started researching Autosuggest with ColdFusion and I believe this is the way I will go.  Since the application I am writing already utilizes jQuery I have a basic idea of what I need to do.  I will post the code I come up with as the answer to this question, unless someone answers it before I do. ;)  I agree as well, 2500 results is too much, especially when that list will grow far beyond 2500 in the future.

Comment: If you mean use CF's built in autosuggest functionality ie `cfinput`, my recommendation is *don't* :) Use jQuery. While CF's UI stuff does work, by the time a CF version is released the bundled JS libraries are already outdated. Plus the bundled features are difficult to customize. You are better offer using jQuery: much easier to control and update.

Comment: Oh I agree 100%!  I don't use any of the CF built ins.  I am also using Lucee so most of those tags aren't supported anyway.  I spend a lot of time here: https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way