# Append to JSON array with ColdFusion, taking Null values into consideration?

Tags: arrays, json, coldfusion, lucee

I have been digging here on Stack for some time but I do not believe my brain is getting the hint on how to do this.

I need this JSON:

```
'{"loginHosts":["server1.example.com","server2.example.com"],"sudoHosts":["server1.example.com","server2.example.com"],"CPG":"my_group","mail":"test@example.com","loginShell":"/bin/bash"}'
```

To look like this JSON:

```
'{"loginHosts":["server1.example.com","server2.example.com","newserver1.example.com","newserver2.example.com"],"sudoHosts":["server1.example.com","server2.example.com","newserver1.example.com","newserver2.example.com"],"CPG":"my_group","mail":"test@example.com","loginShell":"/bin/bash"}'
```

There are some caveats.

1. The JSON application I am pulling from, requires these fields be returned, whether null or not:  loginHosts, sudoHosts, CPG, mail, loginShell.  If they are not returned the application complains.
2. The JSON application expects loginHosts, sudoHosts, and CPG to be returned as an array [] even if null.  I.E.: '{"loginHosts":[],"sudoHosts":[]}'
3. The original loginHosts and sudoHosts data (such as: server1.example.com, server2.example.com) must remain in the JSON string sent back to the application.  So all of my new data must be appended.
4. There are many times when loginHosts and sudoHosts are sent to my application as Null arrays.  I.E.: '{"loginHosts":[],"sudoHosts":[]}'

I am developing this on a server running Lucee 4.5 with a Linux OS.  To get/set the JSON string; I use CFEXECUTE to ssh to a remote Linux server to pull/push my JSON string.  You can see the reason for that here: [Populating SELECT with large JSON data set via ColdFusion (Lucee) very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733573/populating-select-with-large-json-data-set-via-coldfusion-lucee-very-slow)

The code I have so far:

```
    <cfset user_list = '{"loginHosts":["server1.example.com","server2.example.com"],"sudoHosts":["server1.example.com","server2.example.com"],"CPG":"my_group","mail":"test@example.com","loginShell":"/bin/bash"}'

<cfset arrayOfStructs = deserializeJson(user_list)>

<cfloop array="#arrayOfStructs#" index="user">
    <cfif structKeyExists(user, "loginHosts")>
        <cfloop array="#user.loginHosts#" index="login">
                <cfset loginHosts = #login#>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfif structKeyExists(user, "sudoHosts")>
        <cfloop array="#user.sudoHosts#" index="hosts">
            <cfset sudoHosts = #hosts#>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>                             
    <cfif structKeyExists(user, "CPG")>
        <cfloop array="#user.CPG#" index="cp">
            <cfset CPG = #cp#>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
    <cfset mail = #user.mail#>
    <cfset loginShell = #user.loginShell#>
</cfloop>
<cfset my_servers = "newserver1.example.com,newserver2.example.com">
<cfset loginHosts = listAppend(loginHosts, "#my_servers#", ",")>
<cfset myStruct = '{"loginHosts":["#loginHosts#"],"sudoHosts":["#sudoHosts#"],"CPG":["#cp#"],"mail":"#mail#","loginShell":"#loginShell#"}'/>
```

The myStruct is then serialized and sent back to the remote server using the CFEXECUTE method I mentioned earlier.

That code works a little but two things are not working.  First, each cfset loginHosts and cfset sudoHosts are only returning the second server in the JSON (server2.example.com).  I understand that I am overwriting my own loginHosts in that CFLOOP but I am not sure how to correct that and also check if the loginHosts array is Null.

I am also having problems preserving double quotes so that they remain in the JSON.  In my testing I get this:

```
["server1.example.com","server2.example.com","newserver1.example.com,newserver2.example.com"]
```

Notice the missing "," between newserver1 and newserver2?

I have tried adding escaped quotes to my listAppend() like this: """#my_servers""".  It seems to work OK until I have a Null value returned in the JSON string.

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!

EDIT ---

Some clarification:

Why:  I am simply wanting to add additional server names to a database.  To work with that database I am required to use an API that sends JSON and expects JSON back.  This has to be done through a BASH shell script that utilizes curl.  As I posted above, this is the reason: [Populating SELECT with large JSON data set via ColdFusion (Lucee) very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733573/populating-select-with-large-json-data-set-via-coldfusion-lucee-very-slow)

I am using serializeJSON() and deserializeJSON() a lot in my application.  The "user_list" at the top of my code is simply there to show you what data I am given to work with.  It was not written by hand.

EDIT 2 --

My apologies for not adding this line to my code above.

The 'myStruct' at the bottom gets populated with the data from the "arrayOfStructs" and then serialized.

```
<cfset myJsonvar = serializeJSON(myStruct)/>
```

The 'myJsonvar' is then sent as a string, over SSH using CFEXECUTE, to a BASH script that then uses curl to submit the data.  Yes, convoluted, but its what I have due to security.

Comment: you're last line is a problem (but not sure if it is "the" problem.) It should simply be creating a struct, not a json string.

Comment: I don't see why you're not just modifying the original struct, as a struct, to begin with, or why you're looping over it when you could just instead access a key directly and then loop over the nested arrays. All you're doing is adding two new servers to the login hosts array, right?

Comment: for example, `<cfset arrayAppend(myStruct.loginHosts, ['newserver1.example.com','newserver2.example.com'], true>` would add your two new servers to the original struct's `loginHosts` array.

Comment: The number of servers can range from 1 to N records depending on what is required.  I am looping over it because the JSON fields loginHosts, sudoHosts and CPG are arrays.  My understanding is in order to append to existing data you first have to set the data and then append?  I guess I am completely wrong?  :(

Comment: since arrayAppend can merge two arrays, the number of servers you are adding doesn't matter, as long as you have them in an array.

Comment: I attempted a very similar cfset as you suggested.  Because loginHosts can sometimes be sent to my application as null, Lucee throws this error: Error: No matching property [loginHosts] found in [string].  So then I looked at Ben Nadel's suggestion: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1654-learning-coldfusion-9-isnull-and-working-with-null-values.htm  Sadly it did not work. :(

Comment: Ah, if it's null, you'll have to create it. can't you just use an if statement?

Comment: This is important.. Is it null, or is it not there at all.

Comment: It is null.  I checked it using structKeyExists(user, "loginHosts").  The struct "loginHosts" is indeed there.  It just has no data.

Comment: well... if it is null, then, it does have data, the data being `null`. :) pretty big difference between a null value and it being an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simplify the code quite a bit. It appears as though all you are doing is adding your two new servers to an existing list of loginHosts within your struct; that doesn't require any looping.

```
<cfset user_list = '{"loginHosts":["server1.example.com","server2.example.com"],"sudoHosts":["server1.example.com","server2.example.com"],"CPG":"my_group","mail":"test@example.com","loginShell":"/bin/bash"}'>

<cfset myStruct = deserializeJson(user_list)>

<cfset myServers = ["newserver1.example.com","newserver2.example.com"]>

<!--- if loginHosts isn't an array, make it one. --->
<cfif NOT structKeyExists(myStruct, 'loginHosts') OR NOT isArray(myStruct.loginHosts)> 
  <cfset myStruct.loginHosts = []>
</cfif>
<cfset arrayAppend(myStruct.loginHosts, myServers, true)>

<cfset user_list = serializeJSON(myStruct)>
<!--- now user_list is a json string with your new servers added as login hosts, the rest of the struct remains the same. --->
```

Comment: Kevin, I am trying Leigh's suggestion above, as well as this one.  Will let you guys know what works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they'll both have the same problem when it comes to null values. isArray might be the best option for testing if loginHosts contains an array, rather than testing whether or not it is null.

Comment: Added a check that will correct both cases where it's there and not an array, and if it's not there at all just to be safe.

Comment: Kevin B - Darn. Beat me to it :)  (Edit) Sounds like the arrays are not `null`, just empty, in which case the above would work fine. @Grimdari - Both answers do the same thing, but Kevin's is better, so I deleted mine.

Comment: TIL you could merge arrays with arrayAppend. I could have probably used that a few dozen times in the past

Comment: Leigh and Kevin B -  Yes, both answeres worked!  I wish I could send you both a box full of candy!!!  As long as loginHosts is either [] or "" the code works.  I hate when I over think things! :D  THANK YOU BOTH!

Comment: *merge arrays* Having wished it existed for so long, now that it actually does ... I keep forgetting it ;-)